# Sed command with ' special character

Tags: sed, special-characters

I am trying to execute the following command from bash shell:

```
sed -i "s/\(update.*\)where /\1 where primary_id = '$primary_id', /" *.php
```

As you see, there is a variable which I am inserting using sed -- i.e. `'$primary_id'`. After executing the command, I see that the `'`'s are displayed, however `$primary_id` is missing.

How can I handle special characters, such as  `'`?

Comment: Where's the output?

Comment: Those quote marks are being included because that's what your `sed` command has been instructed to do. Has `$primary_id` been given a value at the point the `sed` is run? Or are you wanting the literal `'$primary_id'` to be inserted into your PHP files? Please [edit] your question to make this clear.

Comment: What is unclear about this question? It is precisely the issue I face, and I understood the OP as it is currently written/edited. I do not think it should be closed. I don't have the `Cast Close And Reopen Votes` privs as I do on stackoverflow to vote to reopen here on stackexchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make this a bit simpler. You want to replace every occurence of `a` with `'$b'` (a dollar, a b enclosed in single quotes). `c`, what the variable `$b` happens expands to, is not what you want.

```
b=c
sed -i "s/a/'$b'/g" *.php
```

The above command is similar to what you are doing in your problem. Because the string `s/a/'$b'/g` is enclosed in double quotes, variables are expanded, and the replacement string is `'c'`.

If the whole `sed` command is enclosed in double quotes, you need to escape `$`. This is one solution:

```
sed -i "s/a/'\$b'/g" *.php\
```

Another possibility is to quote nothing, except for any character that has a spedcial meaning to the shell (not recommended, but it might be insightful):

```
sed -i s/a/\'\$b\'/g *.php
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly reasonable assumption of requirements from the unclear question, and clearly explains those assumptions up front. +1 from me

Comment: @roaima, it could be because of the `sed -i 's/a/\'$b\'/g' *.php` one which would only work with the `fish` shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas possibly, but references to `fish` and `zsh` are not at all uncommon on U&L (although they are generally flagged up explicitly so people don't assume they're `bash` code)

Comment: Assumptions, assumptions, assumptions. Thanks, @StéphaneChazelas, removed!

Comment: The last thing makes no sense. *quote nothing except for any character that has a special meaning to the shell* is all you ever *can* quote with shell quotes anyway. what do you think you're doing when you quote shell commands? `sed "s/a/'$"b\'/g` also works.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I misunderstand, your command works exactly as expected:

```
$ cat test_file 
update name where a='b'
$ export primary_id="test"
$ sed -i "s/\(update.*\)where /\1 where primary_id = '$primary_id', /" test_file
$ cat test_file 
update name  where primary_id = 'test', a='b'
```

Answer (score 2):

Special characters, preceded by `\`'s will be taken literally.
(Like you've done with your parentheses: (`\( \)`)).

It should look like this: `\'`.
If you find that still doesnt work try: `'\''`.
Alternatively, try the hexadecimal escape sequence: `\x27`.

Also, regarding `sed`: Enclose your expression with:
[***Single***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27_(disambiguation)) [***Quotes***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) (`'s/1/2/g'`).  *Not* [***Doubles***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22_(disambiguation)) <strike>(`"s/1/2/g"`)</strike>.

---

```
sed -i 's/\(update.\*\)where /\1 where primary_id = \'$primary_id\', /' \*.php
```

```
sed -i 's/\(update.\*\)where /\1 where primary_id = '\''$primary_id'\'', /' \*.php
```

```
sed -i 's/\(update.\*\)where /\1 where primary_id = \x27$primary_id\x27, /' \*.php
```

Comment: Why was this voted down? It's correct.

Comment: then why did you edit it? it's still *basically* incorrect even now, even it isn't just syntax error as before. `'` is not a special character to `sed` - but is to the invoking shell.