# Complex sed Command with AND/OR/NOT

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, php, sql

I have a bunch of `php` files which have many `select` commands.

In each query i want to insert a coloumn variable `admin_id = '$admin_id'`
i.e. if the query is `select * from users where abc='xyz' and qwe='fgh'` the query should be converted to `select * from users where admin_id = '$admin_id' and abc='xyz' and qwe='fgh'`.

To do this i have executed the following command `sed -i "s/\(\"select.*\)where /\1 where admin_id = '\$admin_id' and /" *.php`.

The above has worked successfully but am still facing problem with SQL queries where there is no `where` in the query i.e. `select * from users`. 
How can i insert `admin_id = '$admin_id'` in these queries as well?

> The queries in php files are executed by passing the query to the function in following way :
>   `execute_query("select * from $table order by username");`

**Grep**

> I can find the queries still which are left to be modified by
>   executing : `grep 'execute_query' *| grep select| grep -v admin_id  > stillleft.txt`

Comment: In que queries that does not have `where`, `admin_id` should appear right after `users`?

Comment: Related (but _not_ duplicate) [Sed command with ' special character](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253103/sed-command-with-special-character/253117)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using sed, you can use two successive `s` command. To avoid having the second one being run after the first one on the same line, add a `t` command in between; this skips all remaining commands if the preceding `s` command made a replacement.

```
sed -e "s/\"select[^\";]* where /&admin_id = '\$admin_id' and /" -e t \
    -e "s/\"select[^\"]*/& where admin_id = '\$admin_id' /" \
    -i  *.php
```

Beware that this isn't robust: it won't cope with `select` clauses where the field selection is broken over multiple lines, it won't cope with queries that have no `where` but e.g. a `group by` on the same line, it'll mess up if a query contains `where` as a substring, etc. Review the inputs and the outputs to make sure that you don't hit any of the problematic cases.

With perl, you can use a [non-greedy repeat operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers) to stop matching at the first reserved word or end of query. This is still approximative but a bit more robust. Perl also allows the replacement to be an arbitrary expression that constructs the replacement string (with the `e` suffix after the replacement), so we can put a conditional there.

```
perl -i -p -e '
    s[("select.*?)(\b(?:where|group|having|order|limit|procedure|into|for|lock)\b|[;"]|$)]
     [$1 . " where admin_id = '\$admin_id' " . ($2 eq "where" ? "and" : $2)]e
' *.php
```

P.S. that `"…'$admin_id'…"` looks like an SQL injection waiting to happen, unless `$admin_id` cannot contain `'` (and I think badly formed UTF-8 can be problematic too).

Answer (score -1):

If all you want is to add the `admin_id = '$admin_id' and` after `users`, and after `where` when it is present, you can do the following:

```
sed "s/\(select.*\)users[ ]*\(where\)\{0,1\}/\1 users where admin_id = '\$admin_id' and /" *.php
```

Put the `-i` flag if the output is what you expect.

The `\(where\)\{0,1\}` part is a trick to simulate a `?` regex, that means repeat 0 to 1 times, greedy.

Comment: This inserts an extra `and` if there is no `where` clause in the input.